# use github action workflow file of another repository

Tags: github, github-actions

I have multiple repositories with the same github-actions build job.

Currently I duplicate the workflow files, but it is the same between all the repositories, so if I could do an import it would be better.

How can I import the same workflow file in all those repositories?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that at the moment there is no out-of-the-box support for this. Please check this [issue](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/98).

But you can take a look on [GFlows - GitHub Workflow Templates](https://github.com/jbrunton/gflows)

> GFlows is a CLI tool that makes templating GitHub Workflows easy, using either Jsonnet or ytt (Yaml Templating Tool). It can:
>
> - Import existing workflows to help you quickly get started.
> - Validate GitHub workflows are up to date with their source templates and conform to a valid schema.
> - Share common config code and workflows with GFlows Packages.
> - Watch changes to the templates, so you can develop and refactor workflows with fast feedback on your changes.